# ViewMatrix has no need of Up Vector, TargetVector and Pos Vector in LWJGL

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I have a problem in creating Camera in LWJGL3.0. When I use opengl in c++, it need to create an Camera class defined like this.

```
class Camera
{
public:
    // Camera Attributes
    glm::vec3 Position;
    glm::vec3 Front;
    glm::vec3 Up;
    glm::vec3 Right;
    glm::vec3 WorldUp;
    // Eular Angles
    float Yaw;
    float Pitch;
    // Camera options
```

A camera has three vector, Up, Target and Pos, to defined it. It still has Yaw and Pitch to rotate it in any directions. As we know, the viewmatrix can be calculate like this:

```
private void genVieMatrix() {
        // calculate direction
        Vector3f cameraDirection = Vector3f.sub(mEyeTarget, mEyePos, null);
        cameraDirection.normalise();
        // calculate right axis
        Vector3f cameraRight = Vector3f.cross(cameraDirection, mEyeUp, null);
        cameraRight.normalise();
        Vector3f up = Vector3f.cross(cameraRight, cameraDirection, null);
        up.normalise();
        // lookat
        Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();
        matrix.setIdentity();
        matrix.m00 = cameraRight.x;
        matrix.m01 = up.x;
        matrix.m02 = -cameraDirection.x;

        matrix.m10 = cameraRight.y;
        matrix.m11 = up.y;
        matrix.m12 = -cameraDirection.y;

        matrix.m20 = cameraRight.z;
        matrix.m21 = up.z;
        matrix.m22 = -cameraDirection.z;

        matrix.translate(new Vector3f(-mEyePos.x, -mEyePos.y, -mEyePos.z));
    }
```

But when I try to use view matrix in LWJGL 3.0, I find that most common ways to create view matrix is the following:

```
Matrix4f viewMatrix = new Matrix4f();
Matrix4f.translate(camerapos, viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
```

when change the rotate of camera, they just rotate the matrix. How could it be so simple to create view matrix?

So I tried to use three vectors, up, target and pos, to create view matrix in LWJGL demos, replace it with the original one. Then I found there is nothing in display.

My code:

```
private ShaderProgram mProgram;
    private Shader mVertexShader;
    private Shader mFragmentShader;

    private VertexArrayObject VAO;
    private VertexBufferObject VBO;
    //private VertexBufferObject EBO;

    private Cube mCubeData;

    private Camera mCamera;

    private Vector3f eyePos = new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    private Vector3f eyeUp = new Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    private Vector3f eyeTarget = new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);

    private Texture mTexture;

    private FloatBuffer projectMatrix;

    private FloatBuffer mViewMatrix;

    private Matrix4f mModelMatrix;

    public SkyBoxProgram() {

    }

    private void compileShaders() {
        mVertexShader = Shader.loadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, VERTEX_SHADER_PATH);
        mFragmentShader = Shader.loadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER_PATH);
        mProgram = new ShaderProgram();
        mProgram.attachShader(mVertexShader);
        mProgram.attachShader(mFragmentShader);
        mProgram.bindFragmentDataLocation(0, "out_colour");
        mProgram.link();

    }

    private void prepareData() {
        mCubeData = new Cube(0.4f);
        mCamera = new Camera(eyePos, eyeUp, eyeTarget);
        Matrix4f matrix4f = mCamera.getViewMatrix();//GeneralSetting.getViewMatrix(new Vector3f(0, 0, -10f));
        mViewMatrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        matrix4f.store(mViewMatrix);
        //mViewMatrix = GeneralSetting.getViewMatrix(new Vector3f(-1f, 0, -1f));


        matrix4f = GeneralSetting.createProjectionMatrix();
        projectMatrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);//GeneralSetting.getProjectionMatrix(60f, 1.33f, 0.1f, 10f);
        matrix4f.store(projectMatrix);
        projectMatrix.flip();

        mModelMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        mModelMatrix.setIdentity();

        VAO = new VertexArrayObject();
        VBO = new VertexBufferObject();
        VAO.bind();
        VBO.bindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
        VBO.bufferFloatData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mCubeData.getPosDataBuffer(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        mProgram.enableAttribLocation(0);
        mProgram.vertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4, 0);
        VAO.unbind();

    }

    private void prepareTexture() {
        mTexture = Texture.loadImageFromFile(IMAGE_PATH, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA);
    }

    private void _delete() {
        mVertexShader.delete();
        mFragmentShader.delete();
        mProgram.delete();
        VAO.delete();
        VBO.delete();
        //EBO.delete();
    }

    private void _render() {
        mProgram.use();
        VAO.bind();
        VBO.bindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

        mModelMatrix.translate(new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        mProgram.setUniformMatrix4f(mProgram.getAttributeLocation("modelMatrix"), mModelMatrix);
        mProgram.setUniformMatrix4f(mProgram.getAttributeLocation("viewMatrix"), mViewMatrix);

        mProgram.setUniformMatrix4f(mProgram.getAttributeLocation("projectionMatrix"), projectMatrix);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        VAO.unbind();
    }

    public void init() {
        compileShaders();
        prepareData();
        prepareTexture();
    }

    public void render() {
        _render();
    }

    public void cleanUp() {
        _delete();
    }

}
```

Some object used in the code, like ProgramShader, Shader, VertexArrayObject and etc, are just simple packaged class that represent the general way to use corresponding objects in opengl.
the shader is simple, so there is only vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
```

When I do this, I found something unusual. 
In the second way, the original camera position is vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f), the vertices positions' z value is -2.0f.

In the complex method (first explained), the Up vector is vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), the camera target pos is vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f) and the camera pos is vector3f(0.0f).

There is no display in the complex method, I really don't know why.

Comment: If I may recommend, take a look at ThinMatrix on YouTube.  He sets up a camera without the forward, up, and right vectors I believe.  You may also need to create your own math libraries to use that though (since LWJGL no longer contains a math library).  If you don't want to create your own, you can use JOML or check my repository (https://github.com/nickclark2016/Luminos/tree/experimental), and it is based off of LWJGL 2's math library.

Comment: Thanks, I'm following the video now.